# Rails + Koala gem publish post in my personal page from my personal site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala

I have a Facebook page and I want to publish post in the wall from my personal site. I am using Koala:

```
user = Koala::Facebook::API.new user_access_token
page_access_token = user.get_connections('me', 'accounts').first['access_token']
page = Koala::Facebook::API.new page_access_token
page.put_connections("me", "feed", message: "I am posting on my page!ok!")
```

Problem: when I go in my page I see the posts just published from my site but if I visit the Facebook page with an other Facebook account the page is empty and there is no post!!

I think is a visibility problem but I am not resolving.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question that you've verified the user whose token you're using can post on the page you're trying to post to - this is the most likely reason for the call to fail

In this case, you should also be receiving a response from the API with an error, probably `Unsupported POST Request` or a permissions exception